# Location coordinates blank in service.nearbySearch in ionic2 using google-geolocation

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic2, google-geolocation

I am trying to use google maps in my application.I want to show nearby places in map. I have done it using this link
https://www.joshmorony.com/create-a-nearby-places-list-with-google-maps-in-ionic-2-part-1/
https://www.joshmorony.com/create-a-nearby-places-list-with-google-maps-in-ionic-2-part-2/

in this link location.json file is used and location coordinates passed to marker.
what i want to do is i want to take the location coordinates in run time and put marker in map.I am getting the list of places but location coordinated are blank. below is my code and image is attached for output which i am getting.
i have also included api key in index.html file.

what can be issue here?

```
 initMap(): Promise<any> {

this.mapInitialised = true;

return new Promise((resolve) => {

  this.gl.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {
    console.log('got location');
    let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

    let mapOptions = {
      center: latLng,
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement, mapOptions);
    this.addMarker(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(this.map);
    let request = {
      location: latLng,
      radius: 8047,
      types: ["restaurant"]
    };

   
    console.log('fetching  places');
    console.log('google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK=' + google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK);
  
    service.nearbySearch(request, function (results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        console.log('got places');
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          var place = results[i];
          console.log(place);
        }
      }
    });
    resolve(true);
  });
});}
```

[image: Output of my code]

Comment: You can get the **lat** value by use `place.geometry.location.lat()`, the same way with **lng**

Comment: thanks for reply.. but please check image given.. i am not getting values in geometry.location(question mark displayed on image).. thats my issue

Comment: sorry. I don't really understand what you wanna get but if your purpose is just take the coordinates to add markers so you can get the latitude and longitude by using `lat()` and `lng()` functions, it will return the values. You can test by log out those values. hope these things can help you

Comment: my purpose is to take the coordinates to add markers but its returning _.F in location . please see attached image .. i have highlighted what i am getting by my code,

Comment: I wonder why don't you follow the official documentation regarding objects that returns places service: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlaceResult, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlaceGeometry